Up to a null set, is the countable intersection of open sets $O_1,O_2,\dots\subset\mathbb R$ equal to a countable union of disjoint closed intervals?
Suppose $\{O_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is any sequence of open sets in the reals $\mathbb R$. Is is true that their intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ is, up to a null set, equal to some at-most countable union of disjoint closed intervals?
Modulo edge cases like $O_i=\emptyset$ and $O_i=\mathbb R$, I think the answer is yes. In trying to prove this, I looked at the sets
$$A_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^n O_i$$
and drew them for a random collection $\{O_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$. It seems like as $n$ increases, the sets $A_n$ form "islands", so to speak, of decreasing open intervals. To be precise, there seems to be a collection of decreasing sequences of open sets $(B_i^1)_{i\in\mathbb N}, (B_i^2)_{i\in\mathbb N},(B_i^3)_{i\in\mathbb N},\dots$ such that $A_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^\omega B^k_n$, where the collection is at-most countable and the union is disjoint for each $n$.
If this holds, the result follows immediately because each decreasing sequence $(B_i^k)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ must converge to the empty set, a singleton, or some interval $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $[a,b]$; we can take the null set to be the boundary points of these limiting intervals. So, does this actually hold?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I presume you meant “closed interval” as in non-degenerate ones? Otherwise every set is a union of disjoint singletons.

If we are talking about non-degenerate intervals, then this is not true. For example, a fat Cantor set is a $G_\delta$ set, but it almost contains no nonempty open set, so it almost contains no non-degenerate closed interval.

@DavidGao yes, and I also wanted the union to be at-most countable. I'll edit my post to clarify this.

Well, in any case my comment did provide a counterexample. I’ll write a full answer.

@DavidGao that's a good counterexample. A Google search for examples of $G_\delta$ sets also gave the set of irrationals as a rather extreme counterexample (consider ${q}^c$ for $q\in\mathbb Q$), so it seems like I'm missing some assumptions for this claim to hold.

True, the set of irrational numbers is also $G_\delta$. But it is up to null set equal to $\mathbb{R}$, which I’d consider to be a closed interval.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a fat Cantor set. In particular, $m(A) > 0$, $A$ is closed and nowhere dense. Now, any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable intersection of open sets:
$$A = \bigcap_n \{x: d(x, A) < \frac{1}{n}\}$$
But if $O \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open set that is almost contained in $A$, then $O = \varnothing$. Indeed, $O \setminus A$ must be of measure zero. But it is an open set, so $O \setminus A = \varnothing$, i.e., $O \subset A$. But $A$ has no interior, so $O = \varnothing$. In particular, $A$ contains no non-degenerate closed interval, even up to null sets. Since $m(A) > 0$, this means $A$ cannot be a countable union of closed intervals, even up to null sets.
